# Intrinsic quantities of an immersed hypersurface in the Euclidean space

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Consider an immersed hypersurface $(M, g) \subset \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, assume $n$ is the unit normal, then the Gauss and Codazzi equations hold. For example, the Gauss equation reads
\begin{align}
R(X, Y, Z, T)=g(B(X, T), B(Y, Z))-g(B(X, Z), B(Y, T)).
\end{align}
Here $B: T_M \times T_M \rightarrow T_M^{\bot}$ is the second fundamental form.
Recall the Gauss-Kronecker curvature is the product of all principal curvatures $\lambda_i$, or equivalent we may write
\begin{align}
K=\det (b_{ij}),
\end{align} where $b_{ij}=g(B(e_i, e_j), n)$ and $\{e_i\}$ is an orthonormal basis of $T_p M$. Obviously $K$ is independent of the choice of an orthonormal basis.

If $n$ is even, we may expand $\det (b_{ij})$ using the Laplace expansion repeatedly. In the end, it is an algebraic sum of $n$-product of determinants of $2 \times 2$ sub-matrices. These determinants can be expressed by $R(e_i, e_j, e_k, e_l)$ by the Gauss equation. Hence $K$ is an intrinsic quantity.

Question: Are there more intrinsic quantities which are functions of principal curvatures $\lambda_i$?

Comment: The fact that $M$ is a hypersurface means that its curvature tensor has a special form. This is related to the concept of Codazzi tensors (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codazzi_tensor). I don't have any specific references, but there is a lot of work on this.

Comment: @Deane Many thanks for your info. Hope I did not misunderstand. I see there is a fundamental theorem that the Gauss and Codazzi eqn determines the local isometric immersion. I was just wondering if there are more intrinsic quantities can be expressed by principal curvatures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a more detailed comment: The Riemann curvature $R$ is an intrinsic invariant and a quadratic form on $\Lambda^2T_*$. Therefore, its eigenvalues are also intrinsic.

When the manifold is a hypersurface in Euclidean space, the curvature tensor can always be written as $$R_{ijkl} = H_{ik}H_{jl} - H_{il}H_{jk}$$ where $H$ is the second fundamental form. There is an orthonormal frame such that $H_{ij} = \lambda\delta_{ij}$. In that frame, the curvature becomes $$R_{ijkl} = \lambda_i\lambda_j(\delta_{ik}\delta_{jl} - \delta_{il}\delta_{jk})$$ You can now check that in this frame $R_{ijkl} = 0$, except for $$R_{ijij} = \lambda_i\lambda_j$$ This implies that the eigenvalues of $R$ are the products of any two principal curvatures. These are therefore intrinsic invariants of the Riemannian metric.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!